# magento sales/order grid date issue?

Tags: magento, date, grid

Here is my date saved in database `2015-05-05 01:59:09`, But this date format showing in grid like this, `Apr 5, 2015 6:19:42 PM`, the actual date is `May 4, 2015 6:19:42 PM`, let me know how can set date format in `magento` grid.

Comment: This would be default format provided be magento you may need to rewrite sales order grid and update there.

Comment: i am  using custom date format but its not working have any fornat to display actual datetime in grid.